# How to use swift files in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I want to use my Swift files in Objective-C code. I found different link that say how to do it.

My project name is: Test-Project.

I imported #import "Test-Project-Swift.h" to my .m file to use needed classed in objective c source code.

I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDk5zXCFe8) and there is no problem, but I have 'Test-Project-Swift.h' file not found.

Comment: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/

Comment: you want to use the swift file in objective C right? what is your swift file name?

Comment: @SuhasPatil MySettings.swift. yea you are right

Comment: `File not found` - there is no such file in your project, or path to it is wrong, check again.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan, it looks like the problem with "-" we need to change it to "_" - "Test_Project-Swift.h". I've checked Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name in the project settings. Thanks, works for me

Comment: If your project name contains space then replace it with `underscores (_)`.

Answer (score 0):

As we recognized:
It looks like the problem with "-" we need to change it to "_" - "Test_Project-Swift.h". I've checked Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name in the project settings.