# Is it possible to use libVLC in Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, libvlc

I am developing an iOS app related to multimedia in Swift. I want to use libVLC library in my project. Is it possible to use libVLC in Swift project? If yes, how?

Comment: This is 99% likely going to be closed for being too broad. I provided some starting direction below

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do most anything when implementing an iOS app. But, that does not mean it is a good idea. A video app will push computational resources to the limits, you should be using AVFoundation directly since it can take advantage of built in H.264/H.265 hardware on modern iOS device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LibVLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC) has an Objective-C binding called [VLCKit](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/). You can use it like any other Objective-C library.

[There](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) are [tons](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/) of [resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/) on [using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift) Objective-C [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636257/how-to-use-swift-files-in-objective-c) Swift